# Display a view when another view is being focused?

Tags: react-native

I have a `TextInput`, when the text is `onFocus`, I want to display a `DateTimePicker` component.

I have a `AddMeeting.js` component, which contains the `TextInput`, and another component for the `DateTimePicker itself`.

I thought about having a `state` (boolean) in `AddMeeting` that would change when `TextInput` is getting `onFocus` / `onBlur` and with conditional rendering to display / dismiss the `DateTimePicker` from the screen.
the problem is, I already have a show and hide functions in the `DateTimePicker` component itself, and it seems redundant to have the state in `AddMeeting` too.

This is the DateimePicker:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

const CustomDateTimePicker = () => {
    const [isPickerVisible, setPickerVisibility] = useState(false);
    const [chosenDate, setChosenDate] = useState("");

    const showPicker = () => {
        setPickerVisibility(true);
    };

    const hidePicker = () => {
        setPickerVisibility(false);
    };

    const handleConfirm = (date) => {
        setChosenDate = date
        console.warn("A date has been picked: ", date);
        hidePicker();
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <DateTimePickerModal
                isVisible={isPickerVisible}
                mode="datetime"
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onCancel={hidePicker}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default CustomDateTimePicker;
```

This is the AddMeeting.js:

```
const AddMeetingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

_popAddMeeting = () => {
    navigation.pop()
}

_showPicker = () => {
    console.log("SHOWING PICKER");
}

return (
    <>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.addMeetingContainer}>
            <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={_popAddMeeting} style={styles.backButtonTouchable}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-back-outline" size={28} color="#000" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        New Meeting
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 32 }}>
                <MinimalTextInput title="When" placeholder="test" onFocus={_showPicker} />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </>
)
}
}
```

Comment: By the way, your date picker component should have `show/hide` state passed as prop.
Because in most case, other components are responsibility for the visibility of your `DatePricker`

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá thanks, that's kinda what I thought about doing, but this is how they wrote it in the example, and because I'm new to react native, I went with it.

Comment: Anyways, you should be able to customize component as your need. Feel free to do it.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá thanks, I will try to work on that.